# iOS13: How to unblock callback on didReceiveIncomingPushWith for VoIP once its blocked by Apple?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, voip

I was trying to do some other task in VoIP `didReceiveIncomingPushWith` delegate and it suddenly stop getting called anymore on iOS13. Then I found this note on Apple doc.

Thats fine but what I can do to reopen/unblock this so that I can implement callKit now. Because its completely stop delivering anymore in both production/development mode.

> On iOS 13.0 and later, if you fail to report a call to CallKit, the
>   system will terminate your app. Repeatedly failing to report calls may
>   cause the system to stop delivering any more VoIP push notifications
>   to your app. If you want to initiate a VoIP call without using
>   CallKit, register for push notifications using the UserNotifications
>   framework instead of PushKit. For more information, see
>   UserNotifications.

Comment: Hi, Have you find any solution for unblock?

Comment: Yes, @MehulAkoliya you have to just delete the app and launch again.

Comment: @tauheed- I tried to uninstall and install it again but still VoIP not coming. any other way we can unblock VOIP push.